# How to create a Generic StateManagedCollection?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

One example is described **[here](http://sujitmanolikar.blogspot.com/2007/07/generic-statemanagedcollection.html)**.  But the author apparently forgot to include the code for download.

Another example is shown **[here](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/child-collections-in-asp-net-custom-controls)**.  However, this one doesn't quite work (as described in comments).

How do you do this correctly?

Comment: Here is an [updated link to the 2nd example](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/child-collections-in-asp-net-custom-controls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DanHerbert got it. Darn, I spent hours on this too! In the process of trying to answer this question I came up with a simplified generic StateManagedCollection that inherits from the framework's built-in StateManagedCollection, based on the version [here](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/post/2007/05/Child-Collections-in-AspNet-Custom-Controls.aspx). Maybe you'll find it useful. Full source code of my sample project available [here](http://files.tomeofwisdom.com/StateMangedExample.zip).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Web
{
    public abstract class StateManagedCollection<T> : StateManagedCollection, IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>
        where T : class, IStateManagedItem, new()
    {

        protected override object CreateKnownType(int index)
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        }

        protected override Type[] GetKnownTypes()
        {
            return new Type[] { typeof(T) };
        }

        protected override void SetDirtyObject(object o)
        {
            ((IStateManagedItem)o).SetDirty();
        }

        #region IList<T> Members

        public int IndexOf(T item)
        {
            return ((IList)this).IndexOf(item);
        }

        public void Insert(int index, T item)
        {
            ((IList)this).Insert(index, item);
            if (((IStateManager)this).IsTrackingViewState)
            {
                this.SetDirty();
            }
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            ((IList)this).RemoveAt(index);
            if (((IStateManager)this).IsTrackingViewState)
            {
                this.SetDirty();
            }
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get { return (T)this[index]; }
            set { this[index] = value; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region ICollection<T> Members

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            ((IList)this).Add(item);
            this.SetDirty();
        }

        public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            return ((IList)this).Contains(item);
        }

        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            ((IList)this).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool Remove(T item)
        {
            if (((IList)this).Contains(item))
            {
                ((IList)this).Remove(item);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        #endregion


        #region IEnumerable<T> Members

        IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable Members

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IList)this).GetEnumerator();

        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Tough choice for bounty award, but the full source code is super helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: You're not implementing IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator(). If you're using .NET 3.5, you can replace that throw with the following:
((IEnumerable<T>)this).Cast<T>().GetEnumerator();

Comment: Could you please tell me where I can download the sample source code? Coz' the link you have given provides me an error message.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde : what you suggested is not going to work because Cast<T>() have a special optimization : it tests if source is already implementing IEnumerable<T>. If its true, it will simply return the source. Here it will result in calling IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() again and again and in the end will cause a stackoverflow...

Comment: also : calling SetDirty() in StateManagedCollection<T>.Add() method is not good because StateManagedCollection methods already take care of that. If you do so, things like restoring some properties managed by viewstate are not going to work properly.

Answer (score 4):

The **[second example you found](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/post/2007/05/Child-Collections-in-AspNet-Custom-Controls.aspx)** almost works, it's just missing a little bit. All that was needed was 2 methods in the main control.

Add this code to the `AppointmentControl.cs` file and it will work.

```
protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    if (appointments != null)
        return appointments.SaveViewState();
    return null;
}

protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    appointments = new AppointmentCollection();
    appointments.LoadViewState(savedState);
}
```

The code in the example site was pretty decent. It implemented all of the interfaces it should have and did a pretty good job. Where it fell apart was that, despite having all of the code it needed in the abstract bits, that didn't matter because the interfaces weren't referenced in the places they needed to be.

The collection classes being used had nothing "special" about them, other than implementing a few interfaces. The framework won't automatically call these methods. The framework **will** however call the overridden methods I wrote above, which you need to implement in order for your control to save the elements in the collection. As long as you call them, everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the code above the provided solution is ok but i was getting exception - "StackOverflow " cool :) the issue is reproducible by adding a few child items in the aspx page and  switch to Design view to design view of  Visual studio ( Visual Studio just restart and nobody knows what is going on....).

```
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IList)this).GetEnumerator();

    }
```

So, I guess I figured it out just change the implementation of the above method like this:

```
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // return ((IList)this).GetEnumerator();
        return this.GetEnumerator();

    }
```

Hope this will help someone else like me :)  just not to loose few hours to get it work with the designer of VS